# Highslide - How to apply "HTML content" with gray background?

Tags: highslide

Reference: http://highslide.com/.
In the example "With HTML", in "HTML content", how do I apply the gray background, the same way of example "With Gallery"?

Comment: please provide any attempts that you tried.

Comment: I tried to add "dimmingOpacity: 0.75," in parameters (onclick) and did not work Example: <a href = "#" onclick = "return hs.htmlExpand (this, {dimmingOpacity: 0.75, outlineType: 'rounded-white', wrapperClassName 'draggable-header', HeadingText: 'Full HTML content'}) "class =" highslide ">  HTML content </ a>

Comment: add this to the question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to use highslide-full.js, because highslide-with.html has no dim function, and then use this configuration

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../highslide/highslide.css" />

<style type="text/css">
.highslide-dimming {
  background: black;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    hs.graphicsDir = 'highslide/graphics/';
    hs.align = 'center';
    hs.transitions = ['expand', 'crossfade'];
    hs.outlineType = 'rounded-white';
    hs.fadeInOut = true;
    hs.numberPosition = 'caption';
    hs.dimmingOpacity = 0.75;
</script>
```

Comment: The .highslide-dimming {background: black;} is the default in highslide.css, so you don't need to add a style tag to the HTML for it.